# mysql update error with random number generator

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which generates a random number and then appends xxxx to it. 
I then update it to the column

```
UPDATE users SET profile_name = concat( "xxxxx" , CONVERT(varchar(240), FLOOR( 7 + ( RAND( ) * 9999999 ) ) ) )
```

its throwing the below error.

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(240), FLOOR( 7 + ( RAND( ) * 9999999 ) ) ) )' at line 1
```

What is the error ?

Comment: The syntax for CONVERT function is `CONVERT( value, type )`. plz make it correct.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: You can remove the CONVERT function and just leave `UPDATE users SET profile_name = concat( "xxxxx" , FLOOR( 7 + ( RAND( ) * 9999999 ) ) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the executable one and that you want:-

```
SELECT CONCAT( "xxxxx" , CONVERT(FLOOR( 7 + ( RAND( ) * 9999999 ) ), CHAR ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE users SET profile_name = concat("xxxx", FLOOR(7 + RAND() * 9999999))
```